# DataGridViewColumn.PropertyName of sub-object

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

For a DataGridView that is binded to a DataSource, how can I define what to show on a column that contains a sub-object?

```
dgv.Columns["Type"].DataPropertyName = "IDbType.Description";
```

This column contains one object that implements IDbType, and it to display the Description of the IDbType

I would also need it to be editable from the datagridview

Without setting anything the DataGridView shows me the other columns correctly but the Type for this one.

If I override the ToString on the subclass it will display the Description as I want, but then I cannot edit it..

bellow is the interface that is binded on the DataGridView

```
interface IDbRegister 
{
    UInt32 Address { get; set; }
    UInt32 Value { get; set; }
    IDbType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Bellow is the interface of the objects on the Type property. (I need to display the Description property of the objects in Type)

```
interface IDbType
{
    Int32 ID { get; }
    String Description { get; set; }
}
```

One possible solution is to add a Description property on IDbRegister that will get and set from the child IDbType. This way I can hide the IDbType Type { get; set; } from the datagrid and show only the new Description property.

```
class DbRegister 
{
    public UInt32 Address { get; set; }
    public UInt32 Value { get; set; }
    public IDbType Type { get; set; }

    public String Description 
    { 
      get{ return Type.Description; } 
      set{ Type.Description = value; } 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this without changing the IDbRegister interface?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I cannot put all code here, as it is too big, but I included Interface examples